# Can't get PHP Net_DNSBL working

Tags: php, laravel, pear, laravel-3

I'm trying to get working the Net_DNSBL package from PEAR to make some blacklisting checks on domain names, i'm using PHP5.3 and have installed php_pear.

Using the pear command I've installed Net_DNSBL with all it dependencies.

But when I try to use it including this in my code:

```
require_once('Net/DNSBL/SURBL.php');
```

I get the following error:

> Class 'Log' not found /usr/share/php/Net/DNS/RR/A.php on line 95

I've been looking all over internet for any insight on the problem with no luck, y have checked that file on the error line, but i couldn't find anything (actually the line 95 is a closing curly bracket)

I have checked with PEAR that I have installed the Log package and everything looks fine, except, of course, because it is not working.

I'm quite new to PEAR and I'm don't know where to keep looking for the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the PEAR php directory in your `include_path` and `Log.php` directly in that directory.

If that does not help, `include_once 'Log.php'` manually.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply :) The file Log.php is in my include_path. If i try to include it directly i get another error: Call to undefined method Log::exception() in /usr/share/php/Net/DNS/RR/A.php on line 95 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Log::exception(). I'm using Laravel framework, could it be a problem whit names or something like that?

Comment: Hi, the one on the include path is, but LAravel framework has a Log class aswell.